# Upgrade from Windows 8.1 Entreprise to Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have downloaded Windows 10 from my Volume License Service Center. I currently have Windows 8.1 Entreprise, is there a way to upgrade without formating the PC?

I have a WSUS in place, but only want to upgrade one machine and would prefer to do it locally rather than at the domain level.

Comment: I think Windows 10 supports upgrading from Windows 8.1. But it is similar to Window 7 to 8.1 upgrade not like Window 8 to 8.1. Inserting the Windows 10 DVD and running the setup should do it

Answer (score 0):

You can't (in-place) upgrade Enterprise versions of Windows to Pro. You need to upgrade to another Enterprise version.

Also, the free Windows 10 upgrade/licence doesn't apply to VL Enterprise installs *at all*.  Instead, you use your enterprise Software Assurance to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 free update is not available for enterprise users. Free update is given to following versions of windows:

For Windows 7:
  Starter, Home Basic, Home Premium --> Windows 10 Home
  Professional and Ultimate         --> Windows 10 Pro

For Windows 8:
  Windows 8.1 --> Windows 10 Home
  Windows 8.1 Pro or Pro for Students --> Windows 10 Pro

Windows Phone 8.1 --> Windows 10 Mobile

Reference link: [Windows 10 Specifications and System Requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/windows-10-specifications#sysreqs)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my post, I had downloaded the ISO for Windows 10 Pro from VLSC. I extracted all the files from the ISO on my desktop and tried to run setup.exe. It worked all right.

Therefore, yes, we can upgrade locally from Windows 8.1 Entreprise to Windows 10 Pro.

I happened to have some drivers missing and reverted back to 8.1, which worked very well too.